# Continuity of a function containing max and min

Tags: functions

I want to know how to determine the continuity of a function $g$ where $f(x)=x-x^2$ and $g(x)=\max f(t)$, where $0\leq t\leq x$, and $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Comment: By "contain" you mean what? :)

Comment: Its given f(x) in the question.

Comment: The maximum won't always be defined, but it will be if you use closed intervals or define $g$ by way of a supremum.

Comment: @PeterHuxford At what point will g(x) not be defined?

Comment: @QthePlatypus For example at $x=1/2$, the function $f(t)$ is strictly increasing when $0<t<1/2$. There is no maximum value of $f$ on the open interval $(0,1/2)$, so $g(1/2)$ is not defined.

However $f$ does have a maximum on the closed interval $[0,1/2]$ (achieved at $t=1/2$), or alternatively we could replace the $\max$ with $\sup$ in the definition of $g$ which would give the same result.

Comment: @peterhuxford. That means f(x) = 1/2 always.

Comment: Please help me by graphical solution.

Comment: By taking some example like this any one please help me to get this problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem by noting that $g(x)$ ends up being the following function

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} x-x^2 & \text{ when } 0\leq x < \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{4} & \text{ when } \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1. \end{cases}$$

The continuity of this function is relatively easy to verify. The reason why $g$ can be given by this piecewise formula is as follows.

By completing the square, we see that $f(t)=\frac{1}{4}-\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$. Now $g(x)$ is the maximum value of $f$ on the interval $[0,x]$.

The function $f$ achieves its maximum value of $\frac{1}{4}$ at $t=\frac{1}{2}$. When $t<\frac{1}{2}$ the function $f(t)$ is strictly increasing and when $t>\frac{1}{2}$ the function $f(t)$ is strictly decreasing.

It follows that when $0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}$, whenever $t\in[0,x]$ the function $f(t)$ is strictly increasing, meaning that the maximum value of $f$ in this range is the achieved at the right endpoint of the interval $[0,x]$. Therefore $g(x) = f(x) = x-x^2$ if $0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}$.

When $x\geq\frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{1}{2}\in[0,x]$, and since we know that the maximum value of $f(t)$ is achieved at $t=\frac{1}{2}$, it follows that $g(x)=f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{4}$ if $x\geq\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. @ peterhuxford.

Comment: No problem @Rajesh :) I can see that you're new here so please don't forget to accept the response which answers your question the best, by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work